# Is it possible to draw on html canvas with true (real world) dimensions?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dpi

I am trying to represent the blinking of a LED matrix using HTML Canvas. It is important to me that the size of each LED and the distance between them represents their true dimensions in the real world (measured in milimeters, for example).

If I find a "pixel to milimiter" multiplier for one computer (I did this experimentally for my home computer), it almost certainly will fail for other computers (as it did at work, with a different dot-pitch monitor).

So, I wonder if there is a way to draw physical things on canvas and get their actual visual size in a device-independent way.

I plan do work only with desktop computer (laptop maybe), so mobile is not needed for my case.

Comment: It's probably not practical to do that calculation. You would need at least  this info: devicePixelRatio (std display is 1x, retina is about 2x, etc), pixel display size (varies by device), pixel shape, current browser zoom level, current ARIA settings, screen resolution (# horizontal & vertical pixels available on display), and probably more that I'm not thinking of. I'm sure someone has a database of the info you need for most devices--for a price!

Comment: I like the idea you suggest in your comment. Draw a common, known sized object on a flat screen (eg, some  monetary paper currency would give a good sample size). Then have the user put that same real-life object over the on screen image. Then the user can use a range control to resize until the 2 objects are the same size.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge it is impossible to reliably detect the physical size of the monitor from inside an HTML page. You can only know how many pixels it has.

If this is a hard-requirement, my best suggestion would be to have the user calibrate the app somehow. Perhaps you could ask them how big their monitor is, and then scale your app based on that.

Here's a quick-and-dirty example of how that might be done:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function recalculate()
    {
        var mmPerInch = 25.4;
        var textBoxValue = document.getElementById("input_inchsize").value;
        var monitorSizeInInches = parseInt(textBoxValue);
        if(!monitorSizeInInches)
        {
            alert("Invalid monitor size");
            return;
        }

        var screenDiagonalInPixels = Math.sqrt((screen.width * screen.width) + (screen.height * screen.height));
        var screenPixelsPerMm = screenDiagonalInPixels / (monitorSizeInInches * mmPerInch);

        draw100MmSquare(screenPixelsPerMm);
    }

    function draw100MmSquare(pixelsPerMm)
    {
        var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,00,00)";
        context.fillRect (0,0,100 * pixelsPerMm,100 * pixelsPerMm);
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", function() { 
        document.getElementById("button_calibrate").addEventListener("click", recalculate, false);
    }, false);
</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <p>How big is your monitor, in inches?</p>
    <input type="number" id="input_inchsize">
    <button id="button_calibrate">Calibrate</button>
    <p>After hitting "Calibrate", a box should appear below that measures 100mm to a side on your screen</p>
    <canvas width="1000" height="1000">

    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle you can try.](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaCarmody/52rv1mrr/)

Of course, this method assumes the pixels on the screen are square, which they might not be. You could ask the user to enter the width and height of their monitor and calibrate those separately. But I think users are more likely to know the diagonal size in inches (at least in the USA, where I'm located).

Comment: Great idea. I would further suggest, for example, to use a well-known-sized object (a coin), put over the display, and dragging/pinching until match. That could be fine for mobile display (a centimeter/inch ruler display is also often used for that).

Comment: @heltonbiker That's a good approach. My answer here is just a proof-of-concept. It could be made a lot more user friendly.

Comment: **[Here is a way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29787308/1693593)** to calibrate the monitor DPI (PPI) manually.