# HTML5 Canvas Scaling Setup

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, scale, dpi

I am trying to setup a canvas so that I can draw on it using real world dimensions. I want the `lineTo` and drawing commands to be in mm regardless of the screen DPI or resolution.

How in the world do you set that up? On my screen, the 10mm font is converted to 38px when I inspect the `ctx` object but is another size on my phone.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.height = 100;
c.width = 200;

// Draw a 10mm square
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(10,10);
ctx.lineTo(10,20);
ctx.lineTo(20,20);
ctx.lineTo(20,10);
ctx.lineTo(10,10);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.font = "10mm Arial";
ctx.fillText("TEXT", 10, 75);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is simple if you know the pixel width and height unfortunately there is no automatic way to know the pixel size. The best you can do is ask the user what make and model display they are using and then look up the resolution from a predefined list. Or just ignore the display size (people are always zooming in and out anyways) and just use a fixed DPI so that when printing they can opt to print at the true dimensions.

Comment: My problem is I pass my [x,y] coords onto another canvas which is dynamically setup with React and I have no access to its properties. All its input coordinates are in mm. When I render text on my canvas and try to pass a bounding box around the text for example onto the next canvas they scaling does not match.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [this question (with answer)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29787308/1693593). The challenge is that currently we don't have access to DPI information - I guess it's in part due to security areas such as reducing fingerprinting etc. but it forces us to pre-define a list of known devices (or guess which one based on other meta data).

Comment: @K3N, I did some black magic when I realized that the ctx.font converts any text size to px. I put in a 1mm text and parse ctx.font to get the px value back out and use that as a scale value. Was a wacky idea that seems to actually work. As I am not worried about displaying on my canvas to size I just need to convert the text objects into the px/mm that I pass to the apps on screen canvas that is already calibrated.