# canvas.toDataURL() does not alter image quality. How comes?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, printing, html5-canvas

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL):

> The **HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()** method returns a data URI containing
>   a representation of the image in the format specified by the type
>   parameter (defaults to PNG). The returned image is in **a resolution of
>   96 dpi**.

How is it possible to refer to a **print resolution** when there is no printing involved?

I've written [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/turdus_merula/nc4411y5/) that draws an image on a canvas, then calls **toDataURL()**. It seems that the quality of the resulting image is not affected, after all.

I can't understand what does **96 dpi** mean in the docs. Any thoughts?

```
var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
image.src = "...";
// ...
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
window.open(dataURL);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is it possible to refer to a print resolution when there is no printing involved?

The quote from MDN is wrong in the sense it refers to DPI as *resolution* for the image.

(Side note: PPI vs DPI differs in physical properties - but not really important in this context. You'll see me using DPI for PPI as it has been so ingrained since I started using it in the early 90s).

The (somewhat) short answer to your question would be:

Images are only measured in pixels and has no concept of real-world sizes. **DPI is purely arbitrarily** when saved as meta in/with images and function as a *hint* when transferred to physical medium such as a screen or to paper (and the entire pipe-line displaying the image considers its DPI).

As to *why*: The 96 DPI refers to the "standard" (but inaccurate and a bit outdated) screen pixel density so that if you do print your image to paper as-is and hold the paper up against your screen the content on paper should somewhat match in size with that you see on the screen (most people don't [calibrate theirs screens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787308/1693593) for actual DPI, and manufacturers are sometimes sloppy with their drivers, if not a generic driver is used, so there will be a small error margin).

The browser doesn't actually store this information in the image files it produces either (not that it need to, see below).

And just to document, lets first look at the binaries of a JPEG file:

[image: hexdump of jpeg from firefox]
<sup>Hex-dump of JPEG saved from Firefox, but the case is the same for Chrome.</sup>

Nope, no unit defined (0) at position 0x0D. This must be either 1 (inch) or 2 (cm) (and of course no [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) (0xffe1/APP1) as there is no camera/scanner producing the image).

How about PNG then?

[image: hexdump from Firefox]
<sup>Hex-dump of PNG saved from Firefox, but the case is the same for Chrome.</sup>

Nope, neither here. No **`pHYs`** chunk and `IHDR` only contains actual pixel resolution.

And that's OK as an image is *assumed* to be 96 DPI on most systems nowadays so it doesn't have any consequences (where DPI is actually used to affect the image, and no other DPI/PPI is defined).

For you and me in most cases though, a 1920x1080 image will be 1920x1080 on a 15" as well as on a 50" screen. Just ignore...

So in conclusion: When you pass the image through the canvas the image may have a hint embedded that indicates for example 300 DPI. This is stripped off of course when saving out canvas, but it does not alter the *image resolution* (provided the canvas is of the same pixel resolution as the original image) so there will be no drop in print quality (compression via JPEG can of course affect general quality, but for actual resolution there is no change).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Does this also mean that if one prints both images (the original one and the one from `toDataURL()`) with the same printer, at high resolution (300 DPI) - one should see absolutely no difference between them?

Comment: @user115202 not necessarily. If the original did had a hint embedded, say 300 dpi and was 300x300 pixels it would print at 1x1" on the paper (if the software printing it considers the embedded dpi). After going through the canvas the original dpi is ignored and the new default dpi would be 96 so now the image would print as about 3.1x3.1" on the paper but now better match how it looks on screen. This is also why it's partly meaningless to use dpi with images. In print production context you would normally drop the image into a DTP etc. and scale it to the desired size anyways.

Comment: thank you! Which means that upon scaling the images to the same size (when printing), they are equivalent. That is, there's no drop in (print) quality due to `toDataURL()`. If my understanding is correct. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a typo in this quote since they should probably have used *ppi* instead of *dpi* and IIRC the EXIF tag is called pixel-density, but it's a common one.

The ppi in jpeg format is simply a note for softwares to let them know that your 300px * 300px digital image is intended to be rendered at a size of 1in*1in.
So if the renderer is a printer, able to print at 300dpi, that will do one dot per pixel.

This info is written inside the file's metadata, and whatever the original value set in your original image, `toDataURL` will only set the JFIF Density Unit metadata to 0 (no units), and X and Y density to 1 (MDN talks about 96dpi because it corresponds to the most standards screen's display ratio, also used in CSS `px` magic unit).

Comment: "This info is written inside the file's metadata, and whatever the original value set in your original image, toDataURL will set this metadata to 96" This is not correct. No DPI information is saved along with the image formats. EXIF is produced from camera/scanners, but no from canvas. I added an answer with more details.

Comment: @K3N right, it's not in the EXIF data, but in the JFIF one (Density Unit, X Density Y Density)

Comment: Correct, but the browser doesn't use these (it's 0, meaning no unit is defined). Not that it needs to as 96 DPI is assumed to be the default.

Comment: @K3N yes yes it's just that when fast writing this answer this morning I had this JFIF info in mind and badly reminded that browsers will save the EXIF dpi (:confused)

Comment: @K3N ah but yours added valuable info, no need to remove it. (was finishing reading before upvote)

Comment: My computer Windows 10 / Chrome saves out javascript -> Canvas data and opens in Photoshop at 72 dpi, not 96.  This seems unreliable.  I need to be able to set the "hint" for various printer companies who can't understand beyond opening up an image and having the inches measurement read out correctly.  They specifically do NOT want to open up an image and have to size it with graphic editor scaling etc.  So, how does one set this meta data?  Full well knowing it has no real effect on pixel size, but every effect on people opening up the file for print, or in photoshop, etc down stream...